# How to evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \arctan(\sin(x)) \,dx + \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \arcsin(\tan(x)) \,dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the integral $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \arctan(\sin(x)) \,dx  + \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \arcsin(\tan(x))
\,dx$$

I tried using this substitution for the first integral
$$\arctan(\sin(x))=t \rightarrow x= \arcsin(\tan(t))$$
$$ dx= \frac{1}{\cos(t)*\sqrt{\cos(2t)}} dt$$ and I noticed that I obtained the form of the second integral, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Proof without words:

[image: arctan(sin(x))]   [image: arcsin(tan(x))]

(Ok, a very few words: the key observation is that $\arctan(\sin(x))$ and $\arcsin(\tan(x))$ are inverse functions of each other.)

Comment: The words aren't needed! Very nice ;)

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $ x = \sin^{-1}(\tan t)$. Then

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \tan^{-1}(\sin x) dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/4} t \>d(\sin^{-1}\tan t)\overset{IBP} = \frac{\pi^2}8 
- \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin^{-1}(\tan t) dt$$

Thus

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \tan^{-1}(\sin x) \,dx + \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin^{-1}(\tan x)dx = \frac{\pi^2}8 
$$